# Regex to match text between variable string and quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write up regex to match text that appears after the word Example, in some cases this could be written as Examples.

I want to return all the text that appears between Examples(s) and `[text]`, ending with the last the quotation marks.

Sample Text:

````
"In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.  If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.  `'a' = 1`, `'b' = 2`, etc.  ## Example <!-- unlisted languages will use the first entry. please keep python up top. -->  ```python alphabet_position('The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.') ```  ```crystal alphabet_position('The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.') ``` Should return `20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11` ( as a string )"
````

Expected output:

````
<!-- unlisted languages will use the first entry. please keep python up top. -->  ```python alphabet_position('The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.') ```
````

Attempted solution:

````
const matched = test.match('Example(.)(.*)```(.*)```')
````

However this returns nothing (blank)

Comment: Could you include a link to this kata?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Sure:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/546f922b54af40e1e90001da

I am getting the question through the CodeWars API though

Comment: You can adjust your regex to [`Examples?(.*?)\`\`\`(.*)\`\`\``](https://regex101.com/r/UNvh30/1)

Comment: Further the pattern needs to be enclosed in slash-delimiters, not single quotes [like this](https://tio.run/##pVHBUiMhFLz7Fb3lgWTNYCVXN3ry4Hm9GcvBmecMGwQWHtH5@viImctetyiKarro1938MQeTu2QjNz70dDw6YjBlxhbtgwePNmNv2GAKBSYREv0tNlEPDisM9kAeBpmT9cNKyOhMR6ADpQmixZTwYXmE5YwYsmUbPGwVJhgXR/NKrIGHNxg/yTQ/zCzTJ8Nmr1gGfEutYAcfxISVO9@jD5VNxCWJaNXZtcoo8b7etasKXivYVEDcCX95iftP8x4d4dePpkHxzmaWNM74oZiBsth1DiXTycSbTdIFeU6Thrwycr8niohiVpKUKD1Ejaa5rcPrOjNzuJc59UI9imAuPkvFsjOMVP1B7kAICp0L3V6r5VllVuvSlNm4/5b7PYbi@nNXWuv25uKi/vW74W6U/NvTr@sTXFyfO8p3C/3zbtm2rZz1uF7Ksy74HBxpF4aFGlKQDtbY3kLhapZ7Wj8LUDv/TW/@pTfPy5vj8Qs).

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for your case:

````js
const input = '"In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.  If anything in the text isn\'t a letter, ignore it and don\'t return it.  `\'a\' = 1`, `\'b\' = 2`, etc.  ## Example <!-- unlisted languages will use the first entry. please keep python up top. -->  ```python alphabet_position(\'The sunset sets at twelve o\' clock.\') ```  ```crystal alphabet_position(\'The sunset sets at twelve o\' clock.\') ``` Should return `20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11` ( as a string )"';

const m = input.match(/Examples?[^`]*```[^`]*```/);
console.log(m[0]);
````

Explanation of regex `/Examples?[^`]*`` [^`]* ``/`:

- `Examples?` -- expect `Example` with optional plural form
- `[^']*` -- scan over anything that is not a backtick (showing `'` quotes here due to markdown formatting)
- `'''` -- scan over three backticks (showing `'''` quotes here due to markdown formatting)
- `[^']*` -- scan over anything that is not a backtick (showing `'` here due to markdown formatting)
- `'''` -- scan over three backticks (showing `'''` here due to markdown formatting)

You could do a replace instead:

````
const result = input.replace(/^.*(Examples?[^`]*```[^`]*```).*$/, '$1');
````

If you expect newlines do this replace:

````
const result = input.replace(/^[\s\S]*(Examples?[^`]*```[^`]*```)[\s\S]*$/, '$1');
````